# OpenG ES draw pyramid

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

i want to draw pyramid with OpenGL ES. I'm new in openGL ES and what that I have.

[image]

Here must be 4 triangles with colors: red, green, blue, yellow. I don't know what is the problem, model view matrix, vertices or something else.... 
here is my code http://pastebin.com/QCJ8vqPj

this my understanding of pyramid
[image]

Comment: Normally, only triangles that are facing the camera are rendered. The facing is determined by looking at the surface normal. And the orientation of the surface normal depends on whether your vertices are enumerated clockwise or counterclockwise. It seems you just have to flip the orientation of the red triangle, or disable backface culling.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem by adding     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);